# Parsing Complex JSON File to make Survey Screens in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-layout

I am stuck with current given task in which i have to make survey like screens in flutter. There are 5 types to fill survey.

1. yes/no type questions
2. scale type questions
3. Choice – Multiple select – Can select multiple
4. Choice – Single select – Only select one option
5. User input text

Following is the JSON file to be fetched

REQUEST:
{ “method_code”: “4018”,
“company_code”: “”,
“employee_id”: “”,
“survey_id”: “”
}

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "method_code":"4019",
    "survey":
    {
        "id":"1",
        "type":"Generic Survey",
        "title":"Canteen Survey",
        "description":"To review operation of canteen",
        "from_dts":"11/1/2018 3:13:51 PM",
        "to_dts":"11/1/2021 3:13:51 PM",
        "question":
        [
            {"id":"8",
            "text":"How often do you use the canteen",
            "category":"Generic Survey",
            "type":"3",
            "option":
            [
                {"id":"19",
                "text":"Break and lunch daily"
                    
                },
                {"id":"20",
                "text":"Just break OR lunch daily"
                    
                },
                {"id":"21",
                "text":"More than 3 times a week"
                    
                },
                {"id":"22",
                "text":"Never"
                    
                }
                ]
                
            },
            {"id":"9",
            "text":"What do you visit the canteen for?",
            "category":"Generic Survey",
            "type":"4",
            "option":
            [
                {"id":"23",
                "text":"Buy chilled food or snacks at break"
                    
                }
                ]
                
            }
            ]
        
    }
    
}
```

**Following is the note given with api file-**
Note:
Field Remark
survey
question []
type

1. Boolean yes/no type
2. Scale type question
3. Choice – Multiple select – Can select multiple
4. Choice – Single select – Only select one option
5. User input text

Examples below,
**Boolean yes/no type**

```
“type”: “1”, 
“option”:
[ {
“id”: “”,
“text”: “Yes”
},
{
“id”: “”, 
“text”: “No”
} ]
```

**Scale type kind of UI.**

```
“type”: “2”, 
“option”:
[ {
“id”: “4”,
“text”: “Very Good”
}, 
{
“id”: “3”,
“text”: “Good”
}, 
{
“id”: “2”,
“text”: “Poor”
},
{
“id”: “1”,
“text”: “Very Poor”
} ]
```

**Choice – Multiple select – Can select multiple options
like check box**

```
“type”: “3”, 
“option”:
[ {
“id”: “1”,
“text”: “Choice 1”
},
{
“id”: “2”,
“text”: “Choice 2”
} ]
```

**Choice – Single select – Only select one option like
radio button**

```
“type”: “4”, 
“option”:
[ {
“id”: “1”,
“text”: “Choice 1”
},
{
“id”: “2”,
“text”: “Choice 2”
} ]
```

**User input – Text entry. No options required.**

```
“type”: “5”
```

Required output example--
[image: Required output example--]
[image]

I have tried fetching nested JSON array but it displays all data which is not according to requirements.
Please guide me how i can achieve this in flutter.